# How to format Twitter (and other) timestamps?

Tags: python, date, twitter, pandas

**UPDATE:** The problem was dirty data and not a data type issue. The above options SHOULD work if your data is clean. In my case, I had about 10 records where the language code had been shifted over into the timestamp field :(

**ORIGINAL POST:**
I am trying to work with Twitter timestamps which look like this:

```
df.created_at.head()

0    2015-10-23T07:57:45.000Z
1    2015-10-23T07:56:04.000Z
2    2015-10-23T07:48:26.000Z
3    2015-10-23T07:48:07.000Z
4    2015-10-23T07:44:09.000Z
Name: created_at, dtype: object
```

I am trying to convert 'created_at' into a datetime data type. I have tried a few ways of doing this but they all give me errors.

If I try to change the data type I get this error:

```
df.created_at.astype('datetime64[ns]')
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "en" at position 0
```

If I use a tweaked version of @Alexander's suggestion below, I get this error:

```
s = pd.Series(df.created_at)
datetime_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(s))
ValueError: Unable to convert 0         2015-10-23T07:57:45.000Z...
```

This approach gives me the following error:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.created_at, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
ValueError: time data u'en' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z' (match)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  I just used `DatetimeIndex` on the series converted to datetime with `to_datetime`.

```
s = pd.Series(['2015-10-23T07:57:45.000Z', '2015-10-23T07:56:04.000Z', '2015-10-23T07:48:26.000Z', '2015-10-23T07:48:07.000Z', '2015-10-23T07:44:09.000Z'], name='created_at')

datetime_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(s))

>>> datetime_idx
DatetimeIndex(['2015-10-23 07:57:45', '2015-10-23 07:56:04', '2015-10-23 07:48:26', '2015-10-23 07:48:07', '2015-10-23 07:44:09'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. df.created_at is already in the right format but dtype = object currently. All I need to do I think is change it to dtype = datetime[ns]. Problem is that I get this error when I do so: ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "en" at position 0

Comment: btw, I tweaked your suggestion like this: 
s = pd.Series(df.created_at)
datetime_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(s))

...and received the following error: 
"ValueError: Unable to convert 0         2015-10-23T07:57:45.000Z..."
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figure it out?  I looks like the index was included with the time stamp when the data was parsed.